# declining reputation, worsening reputation

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, modifiers

I am trying to write a two-word phrase. The second word is "reputation." The first word is a modifier; it will signal that a reputation is getting worse. "Worsening reputation" fits this description -- but it seems clunky and unidiomatic to me. Is there a better alternative?

"Declining reputation" came to mind, but I am not sure that it's appropriate. A reputation can be in decline, but can it be declining? Perhaps it's fine; I am not sure.

"Decreasing reputation" is not appropriate here. I wouldn't write "increasing reputation" to suggest that someone's reputation is getting better (though I might consider it if I wanted to suggest that someone was becoming better-known).

"Deteriorating reputation" might make sense, but "deteriorating" is just too many syllables.

Comment: Have you looked up "worsening " in a thesaurus? Just pick whichever synonym fits your requirements.

Comment: I did try a thesaurus. Nothing seemed ideal.

Comment: "Damaged reputation" is quite common to indicate that someone's reputation is at a lower level than it previously was. If you have a sentence to fill, that usually helps too.

Comment: *Declining*, *decreasing* and similar words would be ambiguous in this context as they could be taken to mean that one is getting to be less widely or less well known (possibly still for good qualities) rather than that the qualities that one is known for are changing for the worse.

Comment: 'Declining reputation' seems more idiomatic than 'dwindling reputation', if Google ngrams are reliable here. I've tried a few others, none of which outperforms 'declining reputation'. 'Declining' etc treat 'reputation' as scalable/quantitative whereas 'worsening' is more qualitative.

Comment: You could try **falling reputation**.

Comment: Depends if they've gone from high to low (where something like declining or falling would fit) or started bad and just got worse and worse (worsening, putrifying, rotting, imploding).

Answer (score 1):

> A **dwindling reputation**

**dwindling** (adj.)

> Gradually diminishing in size, amount, or strength. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/dwindling?locale=en)

> Declining; growing less
>
> *There is dwindling support for New Labour.* [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dwindling)

---

> The decision in *Ad Lib Club Ltd v Granville* probably represents the
> height of the court's willingness to protect a **dwindling
> reputation**. [M. Davison et al.; *Australian Intellectual Property
> Law*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Australian_Intellectual_Property_Law/00XjCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22dwindling%20reputation%22&pg=PA37&printsec=frontcover)

> Unsurprisingly, Gardena's **dwindling reputation**, coupled with fierce
> competition from the glitzy and glamorous casinos of Las Vegas and
> Atlantic City, as well as from the super casinos that opened in nearby
> Bell Gardens and Commerce, saw players go elsewhere. [James Leighton; *Alligator Blood*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Alligator_Blood/bFg11aMebXoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22dwindling%20reputation%22&pg=PT39&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the relevant verb:

> decline = to gradually become less, worse, or lower
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/decline)

A *declining* reputation is thus one that is gradually *becoming* less, worse or lower. It is a reputation that is in the state of decline.

I imagine some of your difficulty comes from the feeling that a reputation is as it is at the instant you think of it; that it has an instantaneous state that is not declining, increasing, changing or any other similar condition. This is akin to the issue faced by the first people (Newton, Leibnitz and others) who developed the differential calculus. They had the problem of describing the rate of change of things and laboured hard over how to do that when any instantaneous measurement only gave then one value of the thing rather than a rate of change. But the solution is that even over a tiny instant a definition of rate of change is possible.

I therefore believe that reputation may be in a state of *declining* at any time.

Comment: I have rejected proposed edits that change English to American spelling. We use both on this site. I have also rejected a change of “then” to “them”; by writing “then”, I refer to the instant at which the measurement was made, not to the people who made it.